# How to add music to a game in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I ran into an issue when trying to add sound to my game. I added this below to the view controller and when I build and run, I would get an error. When I ran the code below:

```
var interstitialAd : GADInterstitial!
var player: AVAudioPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "gameMusic.mp3", ofType:"mp3")!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player = sound
        sound.play()
    } catch {
        print("file not found")
    }




    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
```

I got the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   2017-05-21 17:35:01.262683 gameTest2[1660:363851] fatal error:
>   unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Can anyone help?

Comment: remove the `.mp3` from the resource name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Bundle.main.path(forResource:,ofType:)` the first part should be the name of the resource, the second part should be its type. That means your code should be:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "gameMusic", ofType:"mp3")!
```

Comment: oh ok, i went ahead and tried it and there was no error this time but there was no music playing when i build and ran it, what do you think is going on?

Comment: @JR_22 no idea, but you might want to stick with SpriteKit and use a SKAudioNode instead.